# why my page is refreshing and not going into the other page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

Timesheet.php , autocomplete.php and insert.php.

My autocomplete.php is included in my timesheet.php and on my autocomplete.php I have a button Complete where is normaly going to insert.php .

But I don't why when I click on complete is refreshing my page!

here some code of my timesheet.

```
<h1>Feuille de temps du Groupe Ohméga inc.</h1>
<div id="pic">
    <img src="ohm.png" width="100" height="85" align="left" hspace="6" vspace="6"/> 
</div>
</br>
        <div id="welcome">
        </br>
            <input value="recherche un numéro" type="button" name="search" id="search" onClick="window.open('datagrid.html','Fiche','toolbar=no,status=no,width=800 ,height=700,scrollbars=yes,location=center,resize=yes,menubar=yes')">

                </br>
            <form method="post" action="choixsheet.php">
                <input type="submit" name="disconnect"  value="Se déconnecté" id="disconnect" />

                <?php

            $_SESSION['usrUserName'] = $usrUserName  ;

            $_SESSION['usrPassword'] = $usrPassword ;
                ?>
            </form>

<form>
<?php 
            $usrUserName = $_SESSION['usrUserName']; ?>
            Bienvenue:  <?php echo$usrUserName;  '\t'   ?>

                </br>
            Semaine du : 
            <input  align="center" type="text" name="timesheetdate" id="timesheetdate" value=<?php  echo $date ?> disabled>
            </br>
            </br>
        </div>

        <?php include "autocomplete.php" ;  ?>

    <!--creation de la case commentaire. -->

</form>
    </div>
```

Here is my autocomplete I cut some part cause its over 3000 line of code

```
<?php
// Connect to the DB
    require("dbconn.php");
    include("Log.php"); 
//chercher pour la colone tache 
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ohmega', 'Something', '', 
    array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from taches ');
    $stmt->execute();
?>

<!-- Insérer donner et envoyer dans la page insert.php pour la BD. -->
<form action ='insert.php' method="post"  > 
<table>
```

// some part are cut

```
</br>
    <div class="header">
        Commentaires spéciaux : 
        </br>
        <textarea  id="timComments" name="timComments"> </textarea>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_val"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
    </div>



</form>
```

So when I click on terminé ( finish) is not going to insert buyt just refreshing ??

Comment: You should try and generalize your problem a little instead of pasting all your code for us to debug.

Comment: I just don't know why my page is refreshing and not going to the other page that my problem :s. when I lcick on the input is refreshing and not going to insert.php

Comment: You have a form action, going to `choixsheet.php` - that determines which page is loaded next. If you want it to go elsewhere, either change the action, or use redirects in your PHP

Comment: choixsheet its the return button to my mainpage and when is refreshing the page is not going to my main page but if i click on this button yes it will this is not the part of the problem

Comment: one more thing..you have a <form> opening in "timesheet" which include autocomplete.php before it get closed </form> And in autocomplete.php u have another form. A nested form isn't correct :S

Comment: and just to make sure I was right I just deleted the button And the problem is always there. always refresh When I press on   <input type="submit" name="submit_val"  value="Terminé" id="end" />

Comment: Oh, I see - yes, there's a second form in `autocomplete.php`. But you've not closed off the first form anywhere, so I assume it's using the first form's action instead.

Comment: Like I said I have timessheet.php who included autocomplete.php and I have a button in autocomplete when I press go to page insert.php

Comment: ohh I see thanks I try to ajust that

Comment: yep that was the problem Thanks didn't know that !

Comment: If you don't mind, post your answer, and mark it correct. This is so it won't be in the "unanswered" list.